# Activate window of another Visio instance

Tags: vba, visio

Currently I have a file name stored in string called **filename**. The file stored in the string is currently open. Issue is, this file could some times be opened in another instance of Visio.

I want to activate the file that is stored in filename string

My current method does not capture this - The code below only checks if the filename exists among the current/one instance of Visio.

```
For Each objDoc In objVisio.Documents
  If objDoc.Name = filename Then
     objDoc.activate
 Exit for
  End If
```

Next

How can I activate this file to bring it forward?

```
windows(filename & " - Microsoft Visio").activate
```

is not working either

I've tried

```
Dim objVisio as Visio.Application
Set objVisio = GetObject(filename).Application
```

which isn't working (maybe due to filename string only having the file name and not the entire file path as well)

Any other brute force methods available out there?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is Visio the foreground window. There are rules about activating windows which basically says if your code isn't the active window you can't set the active window (it's ignored). This is to stop programs stealing the focus from the user's choice of programs to use.

Comment: I just actually found that rule few minutes ago. Which makes sense. In a scenario where in the 2nd instance of Visio, if 3 files are opened and the 'filename' is out of focus, it wouldn't bring it up as active window. In such case, I have to go looping through each open Visio instance to find name and activate it (but how do I go on to do that)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
objVisio.Application.Caption
```

Or

```
AppActivate "Microsoft Visio"
```

I guess another option is to look into this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff766749.aspx

I haven't worked extensively with Visio in VBA, so I am interested to see the true answer here.

Comment: Both aren't working. The unfortunate part is lack of file path :/

Comment: Worth a try I guess. Hopefully someone smarter than I will turn up and we can both learn something new today :)